# Problem scraping a scrolling web page with BeatifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem when I try to **scrape** informations of this [page](https://www.aiscore.com/basketball/20200128).

There i my code :
'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


request = requests.get("https://www.aiscore.com/basketball/20200128")
    
page = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

matchs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"list"})

for match in matchs:

    hour = match.find("span", {"class":"fs-12 flex-1 text-center"})
    hour = hour.text

    status = match.find("div", {"class":"fs-12 color-999 flex-1 text-center"})
    status = status.text

    teams = match.findAll("div", {"class":"w-o-h"})
    i = 1
    for team in teams:
        if i == 1:
            t1 = team.text
        elif i == 2:
            t2 = team.text
        else:
            print("+ de 2 équipes dans le match")
        i += 1

    scores = match.findAll("div", {"class":"flex align-center justify-center fs-12 color-999 w-bar-100 flex-1"})
    i = 1
    for score in scores:
        scs_qtps = score.findAll("div", {"class":"flex-1 text-center isVisible"})
        if i == 1:
            k = 1
            for sc_qtp in scs_qtps:
                if k == 1:
                    sc_qt1_t1 = sc_qtp.text
                elif k == 2:
                    sc_qt2_t1 = sc_qtp.text
                elif k == 3:
                    sc_qt3_t1 = sc_qtp.text
                elif k == 4:
                    sc_qt4_t1 = sc_qtp.text
                else :
                    print("plus de 4 quart tps")
                k += 1
            sc_final_t1 = score.find("div", {"class":"flex-1 text-center"})
            sc_final_t1 = sc_final_t1.text
        elif i == 2:
            k = 1
            for sc_qtp in scs_qtps:
                if k == 1:
                    sc_qt1_t2 = sc_qtp.text
                elif k == 2:
                    sc_qt2_t2 = sc_qtp.text
                elif k == 3:
                    sc_qt3_t2 = sc_qtp.text
                elif k == 4:
                    sc_qt4_t2 = sc_qtp.text
                else :
                    print("plus de 4 quart tps")
                k += 1
            sc_final_t2 = score.find("div", {"class":"flex-1 text-center"})
            sc_final_t2 = sc_final_t2.text
        i += 1

    odds = match.findAll("div", {"style":"height: 19px; line-height: 19px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102);"})
    i = 1
    for odd in odds:
        if i == 1:
            odd_t1 = odd.text
        elif i == 2:
            odd_t2 = odd.text
        i += 1

    print(hour, status, t1, t2)
    print(sc_qt1_t1, sc_qt2_t1, sc_qt3_t1, sc_qt4_t1, "%t", sc_final_t1)
    print(sc_qt1_t2, sc_qt2_t2, sc_qt3_t2, sc_qt4_t2, "%t", sc_final_t2)
    print("1 :", odd_t1, "; 2 :", odd_t2)
```

'''

I want to **scrape** all the scores but there is a problem: I can't access to all of the data in the html page. Indeed, all the informations I want to **scrape** are located in this div:

```html
<div class="vue-recycle-scroller scroller page-mode direction-vertical"
/div>
```

but when I print the html page with `print(soup.prettify())`, there isn't any content in this `div` except `!-- --`.

So my question is: how can I access to the informations which are "located" in this `div`?
I'm open to all kind of answer (maybe do I should use Selenium to **scrape** that kind of informations ?)

Thanks a lot!

Sorry for my basic english

Comment: I think it appending all the data dynamically to that div. That's why you are not getting it in Print. I think you should use Selenium to mimic browser behaviour.

Comment: Yes it was what I thought, but how could I mimic scrolling with Selenium ? Do you know some helpful content on that ?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

As we can not see your script so cannot tell but i guess you may need to check your class name again. if you are scraping any script then would be better using ctrl+shift+C and then hoover on the script you want to **scrape**. it will help you get the right class. hope this helps.

Comment: I posted my script. When you say that I need to check my class name, what are you talking about ? Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: so what i mean, you need to have a class from the script of the website.